# Passing negative values into stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert ID values in stored procedure from .net and the int value for ID is inserting negative value in the stored procedure.

But when a negative value is passed its giving me an error incorrect syntax near '*'.

Please help me.

Here is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HotlinePlusAdministration_ArticleMigrator]
        @Id AS INT,
        --@CategoryID AS INT,
        --@Title AS Varchar(200),
        --@ArticleDate AS datetime,
        @DestLinkServer AS VARCHAR(50),
        @UserID     AS VARCHAR(8),
        @ReturnMsg AS VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Log AS VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @ArticleID as int
DECLARE @NewArticleID as int
DECLARE @ArticleKeyExists as int
DECLARE @Title as varchar(200)
DECLARE @CategoryID  as INT
DECLARE @ArticleDate  as varchar(30)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

SET XACT_ABORT ON -- Required for nested transaction
BEGIN TRAN


-- Check if ArticleID exists in Destination Server

  SET @Query =  N'  SELECT    @ArticleKeyExists = COUNT(*)
                       FROM ' +   @DestLinkServer + '.HL2_61.dbo.Article' + ' where ArticleKey = ' + str(@Id)

        SET @ParmDefinition =  N' @ID int, @ArticleKeyExists int OUTPUT';

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query , @ParmDefinition, @ID, @ArticleKeyExists  OUTPUT;
--EXECUTE sp_executesql 1234,'BRHLSQL8','BRWSQLDC',@return = retnmsg

                     IF @@ERROR <> 0
                         BEGIN 
                                 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                            SET @ReturnMsg = @Log + '<span style="color:red;">ERROR: <br></span>'
                                RETURN -1
                        END


--Delete existing Articles for select page
set @Query = 'DELETE FROM ' + @DestLinkServer + 
            '.HL2_61.dbo.Article ' +
             'WHERE ArticleKey = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Id)
            --'WHERE CategoryID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @CategoryID)  + ' and Title = ''' + @Title + '''  and ArticleDate  = ''' + @ArticleDate  + ''''
Print @Query
EXEC(@Query)
```

When I am executing the code as below I am getting the error.

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @ReturnMsg varchar(1000)

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Migrator]
        @Id = -1591276581,
        @DestLinkServer = N'SQLDC',
        @UserID = N'10c1',
        @ReturnMsg = @ReturnMsg OUTPUT

SELECT  @ReturnMsg as N'@ReturnMsg'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Please someone help me..

Thanks

Comment: This is such a long code snippet. Try reducing it to a 3 line repro. I guess, that way you will find the error yourself.

Comment: I tired to execute the Sprocedure in pieces and found that as i am passing negative value in @Id i am getting that error. but the thing is i have no clue what to do to pass the negative value without the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you convert an `int` to a `varchar`, you have to specify the size:

Try this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Id)
```

and avoid using `str(@Id)`